# Python 3 - How can I open an image in pillow that I already opened using open('image','r')

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I open an image in pillow that I already opened using open('image','r')

I have an image that I opened using the open() function, but i want to use the image in pillow.

Actually, I encoded it using base64, then the program decodes it,then gives you a variable that is in the same format as the open() function has. Then I just want to show the image, if there is another way to show the image without saving it, please let me know.

Here is the code that I use to decode it, just so you know:

```
import base64
image_64_encode = 'this-string-is-big-so'
image_64_decode = base64.decodebytes(image_64_encode)
```

I just want to show the image.

Comment: You should copy a complete example, but probably you can use something like https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes

Comment: Hopefully you opened it in binary... `open('image','rb')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from PIL import Image
import io

# Load useful-looking base64 string of a PNG
b64 = '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'

# Open it with PIL - no disk access required
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b64decode(b64)))
print(im)

# prints: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=64x64 at 0x7FF3B90251C0>
```

[image]

The clue is [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) in the Pillow documentation where it says:

> fp – A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a **file object**.